# How is $styles array populated in Opencart?

Tags: opencart

I am beginning to use Opencart and I am making my own template by copying the default template.

When I was going through template/common/header.tpl, I see the following lines

```
<?php foreach ($styles as $style) { ?>
<link rel="<?php echo $style['rel']; ?>" type="text/css" href="<?php echo $style['href']; ?>" media="<?php echo $style['media']; ?>" />
<?php } ?>
```

I have been thinking for a while, how it is getting populated. Though I have changed the theme to be used as my new theme, it is still populated with old default stylesheets. I will be really thankful if anyone can point me to the direction I have missed. I am sorry if it is a naive question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Styles get added to the array using `$this->document->addStyle()` by the various controller classes. The `$this->document` class is located in `/system/library/document.php` if you want to see the source code for the method